# incrementing the value of a column in a sqlite database using Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm a novice at android, I'm learning as I go. I am trying to develop an app which when a button is pressed, it increments the value of a column by 1.

Here is the code i used to execute my update query:

```
    public void updateItems(String date, String meal){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("Update meal_table SET On_Menu = On_Menu + 1 where date =  '"+date+"' and  Meal =  '"+meal+"'", null);
    }
```

2) And I tried this, it didn't give any errors, but it did not update the database either:

```java
    public Cursor updateItems(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }
```

This is the code for the image button. In the case of the 2nd DatabaseHelper.java snippet, the query was in my MainActivity.java file in the imageButton method:

```java
            imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Toast.makeText(MenuCheck.this,
                        "Wonderful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                sqLiteDatabase.updateItems(date,meal);

            }
        });
```

EDIT:This Is the StackTrace

```java
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wiseowl.mealrater, PID: 12063
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1730)
        at com.wiseowl.mealrater.DatabaseHelper.updateItems(DatabaseHelper.java:61)
        at com.wiseowl.mealrater.MenuCheck$1.onClick(MenuCheck.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

What i would want my code to do is for the app to update the value in the database for the particular column i would've chosen in my code. Any help will be very welcome. Thanks

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your question and add the stacktrace please?

Comment: You did not post the error you get.

Comment: You should bind user-supplied values to parameters in a query instead of trying to insert them directly in the string. See the documentation for examples of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, forpas,  I edited and added my stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you are using this overload of `execSQL()`:

```
public void execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
```

and you pass `null` as the 2nd argument.
If you used this:

```
public void execSQL (String sql)
```

only passing the sql string then the code would work:

```
database.execSQL(
    "Update meal_table SET On_Menu = On_Menu + 1 where date =  '"+date+"' and  Meal =  '"+meal+"'"
);
```

**But** this is the **wrong** way of executing sql statements because by concatenating the parameters you are wide open to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
 
What you can do is use a query to get the current value of the column `On_Menu` and then with `ContentValues` use the `update()` method.
Now there is another way by using directly `rawQuery()`, although it's not documented:

```
String sql = "Update meal_table SET On_Menu = On_Menu + 1 where date =  ? and Meal = ?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {date, Meal});
cursor.moveToFirst();
cursor.close();
database.close();
```

This code is working and is sql injection free as it passes the parameters correctly.

Comment: Thank you forpas! I got it working the way you recommended me to.